# Movie (series?) about human-like zombies unable to feel pain; main female character uses her large nails as weapons

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a zombie movie once that I haven't been able to find.

The story centered around a girl who gets infected, and her boyfriend (or guy friend) tries hard to keep her sane and stop her from feeding. The transition process was hard to notice at first; I think she could still talk and everything, and she still clung to the guy. Early zombie-hood in this movie involved the inability to feel pain, and at one point the girl pushes large nails through her hands and uses them as weapons.

It might have been part of a series.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [*Return of the Living Dead III*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107953/) (1993).

[image: Film still with a creepy looking girl with claw-like nails]

[This review](https://clubzombie.blogspot.co.uk/2011_05_01_archive.html) mentions the nails

> *There are a couple teenagers in love at the beginning of this movie. 
>   The father of the boy in love works for the government in a program
>   where they try to reanimate corpses and control them for use in wars
>   (through the help of an exoskeleton and a gun that freezes their
>   brains (which stops them, and allows them to be stored for future
>   use).  Of course, this doesn't work.  The young couple sees this
>   experiment.  They decide to start a new life for themselves, and they
>   ride off on his motorcycle.*
>
> *Of course, they get in a wreck, and the girl dies.  The boy heads back
>   to the lab to reanimate his girlfriend.  He does.  She starts eating
>   people. But **she's a little different.  She doesn't try to eat him
>   (something about their deep connection).  She is somehow able to curb
>   her hunger by inflicting pain on herself...so she jabs nails through
>   her hands, and spikes all over her body.**  It's a little strange.*

Comment: Looks like the one.  Thanks!

Comment: "a little strange"